# What is Big Data?

Tags: data-mining, dataset, bigdata, visualization

I want to know what is Big Data? Can I have practical example.

How big data can be? I need numbers where big data term is applicable. If you can provide link for case study with actual numbers, with reference to V's of Big Data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I want to quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data), *Big data is data sets that are so voluminous and complex that traditional data-processing application software are inadequate to deal with them. Big data challenges include capturing data, data storage, data analysis, search, sharing, transfer, visualization, querying, updating, information privacy and data source. There are five concepts associated with big data: volume, variety, velocity and, the recently added, veracity and value.*

*Big data can be described by the following characteristics:*

- Volume

*The quantity of generated and stored data. The size of the data determines the value and potential insight, and whether it can be considered big data or not.*

- Variety

*The type and nature of the data. This helps people who analyze it to effectively use the resulting insight. Big data draws from text, images, audio, video; plus it completes missing pieces through data fusion.*

- Velocity

*In this context, the speed at which the data is generated and processed to meet the demands and challenges that lie in the path of growth and development. Big data is often available in real-time.*

- Variability

*Inconsistency of the data set can hamper processes to handle and manage it.*

- Veracity

*The data quality of captured data can vary greatly, affecting the accurate analysis.*

---

To me, big data is highly connected to the deep-learning era. The reason is that during past decades, people could make good descriptions and models of data using machine-learning and data-mining but because everyday new data is coming out, social networks increase rapidly and digital gadgets' popularity is increasing among different nations, the demand for processing data and converting them to information and knowledge is increasing. If we want to use previous techniques to gather information from raw data, it will take too much time, if possible, to reach to appropriate results. In big data and deep-learning era, we need more complicated algorithms and more powerful hardware to deal with difficulties.

You can also take a look at [here](https://www.sas.com/en_us/insights/big-data/what-is-big-data.html) and [here](http://searchcloudcomputing.techtarget.com/definition/big-data-Big-Data) which have relatively different perspective. *Big data is a term that describes the large volume of data – both structured and unstructured – that inundates a business on a day-to-day basis. But it’s not the amount of data that’s important. It’s what organizations do with the data that matters. Big data can be analyzed for insights that lead to better decisions and strategic business moves.*

Comment: Great answer. I'll add here that people use the term big data incorrectly quite often. It becomes a 'big data' problem when the dataset, even after aggregating, summarizing, compressing is so large that in-memory computations are impossible, necessitating distributed approaches. Even if you have 100 trillion records, if those data can be queried in summarized form and handled in-memory, it's not a big data problem.

Comment: @HEITZ Actually I completely agree with you. That is another story :)